# Checking the presence of a file in the bundle

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, nsbundle

How can we check if a file is present in the external bundle loaded in the app or not before fetching it?

Comment: Keep in mind for iOS apps can't have more than one bundle. So, there is no "external bundle" there is only the main bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to know if it's there so you can decide whether to load it or not, I'd just attempt to load it and check if the object returned is nil. If it is, you know it doesnt exist in the bundle.

Answer (score 14):

To check if a file exists in the bundle, use the `NSBundle` class.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                            pathForResource:@"somefileinbundle" 
                            ofType:@"png"];
if (!path)
   NSLog(@"Unable to find file in bundle");
```

Having said that however, it's typically a bad idea to check if a file exists first before trying to load it. According to the Apple docs on `NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:`

> Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the file system or a particular file on the file system is not recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior in the case of file system race conditions. **It's far better to attempt an operation (such as loading a file or creating a directory), check for errors, and handle any error gracefully than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation will succeed.** For more information on file system race conditions, see “Avoiding Race Conditions and Insecure File Operations” in Secure Coding Guide

Comment: Your usage of `pathForResource:ofType` seems a bit strange to me - why did you append the type manually? I'd recommend using this instead:

`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"somefileinbundle" ofType:@"png"];`

Comment: It really makes no difference -- either way will work exactly the same. I started using my approach because I would often change resource types midway through projects -- e.g. from png to jpg -- depending on which was the better fit for the type of image. It was much easier to just search and replace the entire filename instead of searching for the name, replacing it and then manually replacing the extension. Not a huge deal, but it was a pain-in-the-ass in several projects.