# Detecting problematic XIB views earlier

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I had a typo in my nib name and it was blowing up later in code when I was pushing to the navigation controller.  It didn't take too long to figure it out but I thought it would be better to assert well formed earlier to make it easier to figure out.  The problem is it's not nil, it just couldn't form itself properly from the nib.  Is there a better assert or catch to check after initWithNib to catch problems earlier in code?

```
//
// typo in nib name - I want to catch before it blows up inside of pushViewController to narrow the problem
//
ENPurchaseDetailView *purchaseView = [[ENPurchaseDetailView alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"XibWithTypoInIt" bundle:nil];
assert(purchaseView != nil);  // does not catch - it's not nil - just not well formed

// other code ...

// blows up with sigabort inside of pushViewController
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:purchaseView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base UIViewController class that you subclass all your other VCs from. Then you can do a number of useful assertions in the base class and not have to scatter them throughout your code. Here is one that I use

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]

// never do this stuff in production code
#ifdef DEBUG
    // make sure you didn't fat finger Xib name
    if (nibNameOrNil)
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nibNameOrNil ofType:@"nib"];
        NSAssert(path, @"Nib %@ does not exist", nibNameOrNil);
    }

    // make sure there's no problems with the Xib
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil ];
    NSArray *instantiatedObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
    NSAssert(instantiatedObjects && [instantiatedObjects count] > 0, @"Not well formed Xib");
#endif       return self;
}
```

Comment: The assert doesn't fire just as it didn't in my code above because in both cases, the object is not nil.  When I break into the debugger, the view controller is not nil but the view inside it is 0x0.  If I try to check the view ([viewController view] != NULL) it blows up on the view accessor.

Comment: I think you posted this comment at the same time I was posting the additonal nib check code -- took me a few minutes to track the code down in my project.

Comment: Thanks - this put me on the right track.  Base class & #ifdebug definately help - you don't want this code everywhere.  BTW, I got a sigabort on the line before the assert.  I changed the check to this line (which is much faster under debug) and everything is good.  If you want to edit the answer to assert on this path, I'll accept the answer.  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nibNameOrNil ofType:@"nib"];  NSAssert(path, @"...");

Comment: I also surrounded that check with a condition on nibBundleOrNil since I'm checking that path ...

Comment: LOL. I just answered this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545504/checking-the-presence-of-a-file-in-the-bundle/7487235#7487235) about checking if a nib existed in a bundle. I have no idea why I didn't think to use that same code here. Anyway, updated the answer to use the more performant code.

Comment: actually, a combination of the two is needed - my check asserts the file is there and then your checks will catch if the Xib is problematic