# pushViewController failing

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to do a "list of items" -> "item details" kind of an application.
I've managed to do the list part just fine so far. I've also created a new view for the item detail but here I get a error when I click the item I want to see the details.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    ItemDetailsView *detailViewController = [[ItemDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    // ERROR HERE
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release]; 
}
```

So far the new view only have a empty label that says "View Changed: OK". Nothing else.

ItemDetailsView is a view that inherits from UIViewController.

To create this view I went to New File -> Cocoa Touch -> UIViewController subclass.

The error I'm getting is a "signabrt" when I try to execute the line below //ERROR HERE

Here follows the complete message:

```
2011-10-02 17:26:03.582 Teste Data Nav[10035:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/leo/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/FA60D1E7-1B98-4943-98AA-C86A2339AC3E/Teste Data Nav.app> (loaded)' with name 'DetailView''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc25a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f16313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d7aef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d7ae6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x0020f0fa -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2024
    5   UIKit                               0x00210ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    6   UIKit                               0x000c6628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    7   UIKit                               0x000c4134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    8   UIKit                               0x000c400e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    9   UIKit                               0x000c2482 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    10  UIKit                               0x000d2f25 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    11  UIKit                               0x000d1555 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    12  UIKit                               0x000d27aa -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 326
    13  UIKit                               0x000cd32a -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    14  UIKit                               0x000d4562 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 932
    15  UIKit                               0x000cd1c4 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    16  Teste Data Nav                      0x00002d4c -[RootViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 220
    17  UIKit                               0x0008bb68 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
    18  UIKit                               0x00081b05 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
    19  Foundation                          0x0079b79e __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00da38c3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00da4e74 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00d012c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00d00761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffa1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x00ffa289 GSEventRun + 115
    27  UIKit                               0x00022c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    28  Teste Data Nav                      0x000023b9 main + 121
    29  Teste Data Nav                      0x00002335 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Comment: Have you allocated UINavigationController correctly in IB or somewhere else?

Comment: i haven't allocated UINavigationController...

Comment: since you use nib files, I guess you should have one defined at least in IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it cannot find a .xib file called "DetailView".  Make sure that your `initWithNibName:` has the correct string name for the `.xib` file.

The important part of that error is:

```
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </.../Teste Data Nav.app> (loaded)' with name 'DetailView'
```

which means that there is no .xib file in your bundle called `DetailView`.  Make sure that you use the correct name of the file:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    ItemDetailsView *detailViewController = [[ItemDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemDetailsView" bundle:nil];

    // ERROR HERE
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release]; 
}
```

---

Edit (from comments) connect the view to the `File's Owner` like so:

[image]

---

Make sure that `self` has a `navigationController` parent.  If this is the main view that appears when the app starts up, you need to add a UINavigationController to the `MainWindow.xib` and set its rootViewController to the view controller with this table.

You can test this out by doing:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSLog("self.navController view controllers: %@", [[[self navigationController] viewControllers] description]);
    // Or something like this:
    if (self.parentViewController == self.navigationController) {
        NSLog(@"I have a nav controller dad!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"I have no nav controller!");
    }
    // ItemDetailsView *detailViewController = [[ItemDetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    // ERROR HERE
    // [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    // [detailViewController release]; 
}
```

If the NSLog prints out an array of view controllers, then there is another problem, but if it throws an error on the `NSLog` or it prints out an empty array, then your `self` does not have a `navigationController` parent.

Comment: the result from first log: "2011-10-02 17:16:06.835 Teste Data Nav[9947:b303] self.navController view controllers: (
    "<RootViewController: 0x4b420e0>"
)" and "I have a nab controller dad!"

Comment: i posted it on the question...if u need more info pls ask

Comment: no luck... does the error has something to do with the string i pass as parameter?

Comment: error changed!!! .xib file name was wrong... now error is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ItemDetailsView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: DID iT!!! i messed around so much that i must have broken something... since it was a simple interface i deleted it and rebuilt it maintaining the name... and then it worked!

Comment: Very cool!  Glad that got fixed for ya @Leonardo!!  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same issue but I had an issue where pushing a view was blowing up with a sigabort.

In my case I had a typo in the name of Xib I was initing the detail view with.  It can also cause the same issue if for some reason the Xib isn't well formed.  In both cases, it will return you a non nil object and it doesn't blow up until you try and push it.

Here was my question on how to detect it earlier:

[Detecting problematic XIB views earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486373/detecting-problematic-xib-views-earlier)

As a test, you can also try to create some other trivial view and push that.  If that works then you've narrowed the problem down to a typo in the push, a typo in the name of the view or a non-well formed XIB file.

Hope that helps get you on the right track ...